# Choose which application uses which network on Windows 10

Tags: windows, networking, connection

I'm unsure if this is the right place to ask this, but I want to choose which application uses which network on my Windows 10 OS. I don't know if this is possible at all, but I figured if it is, someone here might be able to help.

Basically, some programs will update/download large files, which it can do fairly quickly, but while the download is in progress my connection speed is crippled. I cannot do anything while the download is happening. I can tether my 4G to my pc which also runs quite quickly, so if it's possible, I'd like to assign my wifi connection to those programs that are downloading, while the rest of my computer uses the tethered connection.

Is this possible with stock windows features and/or third party software, or is this a complete impossibility? Thanks for any advice in advance!

And just to reassure anyone who'd like to ask: Yes, I have already researched the topic and I couldn't find any relevant articles, forum posts or tutorials. My search terms were as clear as it's gonna get, any more alteration to them and I'm asking different questions entirely.

Comment: Can you confirm that you are referring to programs that are identifiable bits of software that are separate from, say, your browser? Can you confirm if the programs that "update/download large files" are doing so from a private server or from the general internet? If the latter are there some restricted destinations that provide the updates? if so then the solution could be in **routing**.

Comment: An example software I would find this feature useful for would be uTorrent. Other examples might be game launchers (which handle downloads/updates), or online games. I don't see how a browser would be any different, but I don't know anything about this :D. (note: I didn't mean a browser should use different networks for different tabs, the browser itself could use 1 network, while other applications use the other(s)).

Comment: Then I think that routing cannot help you, sorry